# How to comment out a line in express data modeling language

Tags: schema, metadata, data-modeling, step

Express language is a data modeling language speficied in ISO 10303

I'm wondering how to comment on a line of code with this language?

Like /* in java, what is the corresponding operator in express language?

Comment: Have you tried `//` or `--`?

Comment: I found the answer: (* comments *). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The Express Data Modeling Language is an [Extended Backus-Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) based on [Wirth Syntax Notation](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/niklaus-wirth/ebnf.pdf). There are two notations for comments.

1. Multi-line comments are wrapped delimited by `(*...*)`.
2. [Comments to the next carriage return](http://www.geocities.ws/schulerrw/express/EXPRESS_data_modeling.pdf) begin with `--`. Like `#` in a Bash script file.

An example:

```
SCHEMA plant_spatial_configuration;
  (* Add Schema Here *)
END_SCHEMA; -- plant_spatial_configuration
```